# mount: / not mounted or bad option

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, raspbmc

I'm running a custom Raspbmc build on my raspberry pi.
On startup, I always see the message

```
mount: / not mounted or bad option
```

The filesystem is still mounted, but still want to know what's causing the trouble.

my `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults,noatime,nodiratime         0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  rw,nosuid,noatime,nodiratime,gid=5,mode=620        0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    ro,noatime,nosuid,nodiratime         0       0
UUID=7e790ee3-660b-46ab-8378-d8ea91730162  /               ext4    defaults,data=writeback,nobh,nodiratime,noatime 0       0
tmpfs           /home/pi/.xbmc/temp     tmpfs   rw,size=5M,nosuid,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,gid=1000,uid=1000     0       0
/tmp            /var/tmp                none    rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,bind     0       0
```

Comment: The only odd thing I see is that `nodiratime` [is redundant](http://lwn.net/Articles/245002/) on top of `noatime`.

Comment: UUID;; add the device path and check; like `/dev/sda`

Comment: At what point in the boot process do you see this message?